# Semi-continuity of $f(x) = x$ on $\mathbb{R}_+$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Continuity is stronger than semi-continuity, and $f(x) =x$ is continuous so it is semi-continuous (upper and lower).

However, when I think about this function, $f(x) =x$, and one definition of upper semi-continuity is that 
$$
\{x: f(x)<y\} \text{ is open } \forall y
$$
for the case of $f(x) =x$ the above-defined set is a half-open set, $[0,y)$, which is not an [open set according to this wiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Half-Open_Real_Interval_is_not_Open_Set), so then $f(x) = x$ is not upper semi-continuous on $\mathbb{R}_+$?

But that isn't true, so I made a mistake somewhere. Could someone please point it out to me?

Comment: It's open in the subspace topology on $\mathbb{R}_+$.

Comment: I considered that then thought I was wrong -.- Alright, well thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a half-open interval $[a,b)$ is not an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (with the usual topology), half-open intervals $[0,y)$ are open subsets of $\mathbb{R}_{+}=[0,\infty)$ if this set is given the subspace topology.

Indeed, $[0,y)=(-1,y)\cap\mathbb{R}_{+}$, hence is open in $\mathbb{R}_+$. Note that all half-open intervals $[a,b)$ with $a>0$ will still not be open in $\mathbb{R}_{+}$.

Comment: So it is an open set if we give $[0,+\infty)$ the subspace topology. When we are considering a subset of $X$ (from the topological space $(X,\tau)$, do we always give it the subspace topology (unless stated otherwise)?

Comment: That's the most common choice, yes. It's the natural choice if you're considering restrictions of functions on $X$ to a subset of $X$.

Comment: Alright. Thanks a bunch.